# Monitor is blacking out during gaming. I can only play in windowed mode

Tags: display

I have a problem with my monitor AOC blacking out during gaming.

My computer setup:

- Monitor: AOC, model number 27G2, power rating:100 – 240 V, energy usage: 28 W, frequency 144 Hz, it is connected by HDMI cable
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X, 6-Core
- Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
- RAM: 32 GB
- System: 64-bit
- Windows: Windows 10 Home

Description of an issue in more detail: The vast majority of videogames that I own can be played only in windowed mode, otherwise the screen keeps blacking out during game.

The severity of black screen during gameplay can differ based on games I play. Sometimes the game stays black the entire time, sometimes it flickers and I can see everything in between those flashes.

Sometimes it is so bad, that I can´t even access the main menu of the game. I do hear the sound, so I assume the game started but I see nothing and it makes switching to windowed mode in main menu options impossible. In extreme cases, the game can´t be minimized by hitting windows key and/or ended by using the CTRL+ALT+DEL („end the task“ command) and I have to push the reset button on my computer to force a complete shut down and restart the computer again.

In those cases, in which it is possible to use CTRL + ALT + DEL command, I usually end the game and restart the computer. After re-launching the game again, this will sometimes help to get into main menu and set a windowed mode. It doesn´t, however, fix the issue of not being able to play the game in full screen without blacking out. Some games can´t be displayed in windowed mode, which makes them not possible to play at all.

Example of games that black out:

- The Wolf Among Us (can be played in windowed mode)
- Witchy Life Story (can be played in windowed mode)
- The Abbey
- Unavowed
- Day of the Tentacle: Remastered
- The Sims 4 (can be played in windowed mode)
- Planet Zoo (can be played in windowed mode)
  …

What I tried doing in order to fix it, but it didn´t work:

1. Switch Power Options plan in Control Panel
2. Restart the computer
3. Update graphic card driver
4. Update Windows
5. Check, if the HDMI cable is connected correctly
6. Check resource usage during gameplay in task manager
7. Monitor the temperature of the system components

Comment: Interesting problem.  I only have a wild guess as to why the problem occurs, and sadly no way to fix it.  Perhaps the games want to use a screen resolution not supported by your computer.

Comment: I doubt its monitor related, but have you tried a different monitor to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Many games modify the resolution of the screen while playing in non-windowed mode, but cannot do so in windowed mode. Try to reduce the frequency of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all replies. My brother helped me solve the issue yesterday! There are two different HDMI slots at the back of my monitor. One for HDMI 1 and the other for HDMI 2. The HDMI cable was plugged in to HDMI 2. After we plugged the cable into HDMI 1, there hasn´t been any problem with blacking out and I can finally put games on full-screen.

It is a custom built gaming computer, built by IT professionals. My brother has the same setup but with a different monitor. He never had any issue with blacking out screen or not being able to play on full screen. I never thought the problem could be in a cable plugged in a different slot. I always assumed it doesn't matter to which slot I plug it in, as long as it is an HDMI slot and the cable fits. Maybe the HDMI 2 slot itself was/is damaged in some way even though I can´t see it from the outside and inserting cable into it goes smoothly. Either way, I am glad that the problem was fixed.